# Date to DateTime conversion in DataWeave 2

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

Input date is coming in this format "2022-04-30" and I want to convert it to date time and time should be zeros like 2022-05-15T00:00:00Z.

How it can be achieved using DataWeave 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the input string to a Date, then add the time to create a DateTime output. Then just convert to String. The default pattern seem to be adequate that you need.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var sourceDate="2022-04-30"
---
(sourceDate as Date {format: "yyyy-MM-dd"} ++ |00:00:00Z|) as String
```

Output:

```
"2022-04-30T00:00:00Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result as String you can just Append "T00:00:00Z" to your date string

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var sourceDate="2022-04-30"
---
sourceDate ++ "T00:00:00Z"
```

And if you want a `DateTime` Object you can just coerce it to `DateTime` using `as` keyword. It will work as your date string is already in the required format.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var sourceDate="2022-04-30"
---
(sourceDate ++ "T00:00:00Z") as DateTime
```

Comment: It is better not to use string manipulation to construct dates/times if the language provides native date/time construction.